# How do I return an image to a view from a private Azure Blob Stroage account in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blob, azure-blob-storage

I've set my Azure blob storage containers to private and I have a shared access key that I've defined within my asp.net core application.  For jobs such as listing the contents of the blob storage, it works well but now I find myself needing to bring back an image file to show within my view.  The problem is that when I return the blob, yes I can access it in the controller but it just returns the string to its location, accessing that location without the access key returns the error `Resource not found`, which is expected.

My question is, how do I return an image blob which requires the shared access key to my view?  Here is my code so far which, only returns the Uri as a string which isn't any use for the above-mentioned reason.  Do I need to download the image and store it temporarily or something?

**CarController Usings**

```
using Azure.Storage.Blobs;
using Azure.Storage.Blobs.Models;
```

**CarController.cs**

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Edit(int id)
{
    var car = _carService.GetCar(id);

    string strContainerName = "uploads";    
    string filePrefix = "car/" + id + "/car-image.jpg";
    var filelist = new List<BlobListViewModel>();

    BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(accessKey);
    BlobContainerClient containerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(strContainerName);

    //Get the specific image 
    var blob = containerClient.GetBlobClient(filePrefix);

    //I'm binding to a view model as a string, which, as I say, doesn't work for security reasons.
    var data = new BlobListViewModel {
        FileName = blob.Uri.ToString()
    };

        return View(data);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To read from a private container, you would need to create a [`Shared Access Signature`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/delegate-access-with-shared-access-signature) on either the blob or the blob container with at least `Read` permission.

Here's the code you can use. In this, I am creating a SAS Token on the blob with `Read` permission that will expire after 1 minute from the time it was created.

```
        BlobSasBuilder blobSasBuilder = new BlobSasBuilder()
        {
            BlobContainerName = strContainerName,
            BlobName = filePrefix,
            ExpiresOn = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(1),
        };
        blobSasBuilder.SetPermissions(BlobAccountSasPermissions.Read);
        var sasToken = blobSasBuilder.ToSasQueryParameters(new Azure.Storage.StorageSharedKeyCredential(accountName, accountKey)).ToString();
        var blob = containerClient.GetBlobClient(filePrefix);
        var blobSasUrl = blob.Uri.ToString() + "?" + sasToken;
        //I'm binding to a view model as a string, which, as I say, doesn't work for security reasons.
        var data = new BlobListViewModel
        {
            FileName = blobSasUrl
        };
```

Comment: Hi Gaurav, your explanation also helped me in a situation. However, I have another question... I have this container where my application can upload, delete and read blobs from it. But, just like the example from Yanayaya, I have a MVc View where users can view the images that stored in this private container. If I re-generate the sasToken for every request to view a blob, will I also lose the sasToken that I previously used to upload a blob?